# Can't print strings using a pipe

Tags: c, pipe

I'm trying to get my very first pipe work: basically I have witten a program that should display on screen what's typed in. The thing is only a few chars are printed (often only the first) and I am really struggling to get why. My code is:

```
if ( pid > 0 ) //If I'm the parent
{
    close(fd[0]);
    //as long as something is typed in and that something isn't 
    // the word "stop"
    while (((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0) && 
           (strncmp(buffer, "stop", 4) != 0))
    {
        //shove all the buffer content into the pipe
        write(fd[1], buffer, n);
    }

}
else //If I am the child
{
    close(fd[1]);

    //as long as there's something to read
    while (pipe_read = read(fd[0], buf, BUFFERSIZE) > 0)
    {
        //display on the screen!
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, pipe_read);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your termination condition seems a bit off in at least two ways - 1) it only looks at the first four bytes of a potentially `BUFFERSIZE`-sized collection of input, and 2) it assumes that `n = read(...)` returned something greater than 4...

Comment: @twalberg Thank you for your notes. So your recommendations are that I substitute 4 with BUFFERSIZE and... I'm afraid I don't get point 2, will you please dumb it down for me a little bit?

Comment: `read()` is allowed to return, e.g. 2, even though you requested `BUFFERSIZE`, in which case, your `strncmp()` tries to read past the end of what `read()` returned. And, no, don't just substitute 4 with `BUFFERSIZE`, you need to actually scan the amount of data returned and see if your search phrase is anywhere within, not just at the beginning. It may also be complicated by one iteration returning `st` at the end of the buffer and the next iteration returning `op` at the beginning... In other words, it's just not that simple.

Comment: If your compiler did not warn you about the problem, you either need to turn on more warnings, or you need to get a better compiler.  With `gcc`, use `-Wall` and fix the code so it does not witter.  It's better if you use `-Wextra` too.  If the compiler did give you a warning, pay attention to what it says.  Remember, it knows more about C than you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (pipe_read = read(fd[0], buf, BUFFERSIZE) > 0)
```

The operator `>` has a higher priority than `=`. `pipe_read` will have the value of the expression:

```
read(fd[0], buf, BUFFERSIZE) > 0
```

That is 1 or 0, according to the result of the comparison. That's why `write` is printing only one character.

```
while ((pipe_read = read(fd[0], buf, BUFFERSIZE)) > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you. It was something so stupid I've missed it completely.